# Based on user input I would like to find by name for a object within a list I have in my CLI

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I am making a CLI it has 100 objects each has a name and I would like to create an option to search my list of 100 objects to find the object by name. What would be the best implementation to use here.

To start with I am assuming in Ruby I can use .find ? My current WIP is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
class PokeDEXCLI::Pokemon
    attr_accessor :name, :id, :height, :weight

    @@all = []

    def initialize(attr_hash)
        attr_hash.each do |key, value|
            self.send("#{key}=", value) if self.respond_to?("#{key}=")
    end
    self.save
  end

 def save
    @@all << self
 end

 def self.all
    @@all
 end
end
```

My thought was I could search by input to find by doing something like this first?

```
def self.find_by_name(input)
      puts " Would you like to search by pokemon name? Please type in your query."
      input = gets.chomp
       if @@all.include? input
          (this is where I am unsure how to compare input to the :name attribute)
end
```

So I believe I will use the below snippet. My other question is can I add a default argument to name so it will return nil if there is no match?

```
class Pokemon
  def self.find_by_name(name = nil)
    @@all.select { |pokemon| pokemon.name.include?(name) }
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a huge assumption. Could you find that method in [the documentation for `Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html)?

Comment: You are correct I think I was thinking of it in correctly. I essentially need to find a name compare it to users input. So what would be the best way to find a name  based on user input to search for the name.

Comment: That's a really vague statement. Find in terms of what? Substring match? Exact match? By some other identifier? It'd help to show the data you're searching, how you're intending to search for it, and your expected output of the search.

Comment: So that is my current pokemon class I want to create a find_by_name method to search through my array of them and display that pokemons info if the user input matched the name of a pokemon. My thought was I could use something like this to find a name.  ``` def self.find_by_name(input)

Comment: From a design perspective try and separate your "index" from your object class. That is keep `Pokemon` focused on implementing the details of that object, and then have an `Index` type class that handles collections. This will save a lot of pain and anguish, as well as avoid the use of subtly tricky and fussy class variables like `@@all`.

Comment: At some point you may want to look at shifting this to a framework like Rails where you get a subsystem like ActiveRecord to help you out.

Comment: @tadman, Rails - brhh ;)

Comment: @Fabio There's also [Sequel models](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net) but honestly ActiveRecord does a ton of stuff and isn't all that hard to figure out. With it you can then build a web app pretty easily.

Comment: @tadman, _ActiveRecord does a ton of stuff_ - this is frightening me ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby approach here is to use a Hash:

```
OBJECTS = {
  shoe: 'A shoe',
  rose: 'A red flower',
  dog: 'A yappy dog'
  cat: 'Some orange blur'
}
```

This doesn't have to be a constant as it is here, you could easily have a variable, but if the data never changes constants are more efficient in terms of impact on performance.

Where you can reference it like this:

```
OBJECTS[:shoe]
```

Or based on input:

```
OBJECTS[gets.chomp.to_sym]
```

Answer (score 0):

If collection accepts objects with already existing names, then use `select` method to return collection of matched names

```
class Pokemon
  def self.find_by_name(name)
    @@all.select { |pokemon| pokemon.name == name }
  end
end
```

If you want to find objects which name contains given string, use same approach with different condition

```
class Pokemon
  def self.find_by_name(name)
    @@all.select { |pokemon| pokemon.name.include?(name) }
  end
end
```

If collection accepts only unique names, then collection could be implemented by using `Hash`

```
class Pokemon
  @@all = {}

  def self.find_by_name(name)
    @@all[name]
  end

  def save
    @@all[name] == self
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by collection  what are you referring to exactly when you say that?

Comment: By collection I mean any type which implements `each` method. For example `Array`, `Hash`, `Set`. In context of this question it is Array

Answer (score 0):

this class method could help you if your 'Pokemon' class have attr_accessor 'name'

```
def self.find_by_name(search_string)
    result = []
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self) { |pokemon| result << pokemon if pokemon.name.include?(search_string) }
    result
  end
```

it will return an array of pokemons with name, including the search string

Comment: I understand whats happening in the hash but can you elaborate what the ObjectSpace.each_object(self) is doing?

Comment: If you will put this method to your Pokemon class, ObjectSpace will operate with all of initialized objects in parent class (Pokemon in this particular case). And if you will call ```ObjectSpace.methods``` you will find another useful methods. Also you can read this post https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ObjectSpace.html